# Using Glucose instead of Fructose

Tags: baking, substitutions, sugar

My recipe calls for 100g of fructose, I don't have any. Can I use Glucose instead? If so would the amount be the same? If not what could I use instead of the fructose?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe not. It depends on why it's in the recipe. Please post the whole recipe, else we have no chance of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a pastry guy, and I haven't worked with pure glucose before, but it looks like this probably isn't an ideal substitution.  Regular table sugar (sucrose) is composed of [glucose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose) and [fructose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fructose), and of the two, [fructose is more than twice as sweet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fructose#mediaviewer/File:Relativesweetness.png).  So a simple substitution will leave your end product much less sweet than it should be, and increasing the amount of glucose instead could mess up your recipe in other ways.

You could try a slightly higher amount (maybe 125g?) of a high-fructose sweetener such as high fructose corn syrup or agave nectar to attain a similar sweetness without altering the proportions too much.

Comment: Neither high fructose corn syrup nor agave nectar are especially high in fructose, both seem to be around 50% fructose only. The OP could just go for regular table sugar if only the sweetness mattered, and won't have to take the extra liquid into account.

Comment: @rumtscho But the odd thing is, a syrup containing equal parts glucose and fructose is actually sweeter than just a syrup of dissolved sucrose. Ever made invert sugar syrup?